# How to show carousel dots in AMP?

Tags: carousel, show, amp-html

In this carousel,
how do I show dots?

```html
<amp-carousel layout=fixed-height height=400 type=slides autoplay controls loop arrows dots='.'>
  <amp-img src="img/slaid.jpg" layout=fixed-height height=400></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="img/slaid.jpg" layout=fixed-height height=400></amp-img>
</amp-carousel>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in this codelab:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-interactivity-in-amp/index.html

The final code is here:

```
<amp-carousel type="slides" layout="fixed-height" height=250 id="carousel" on="slideChange:AMP.setState({selected: {slide: event.index}})">
  <amp-img width=200 height=250 src="./shirts/black.jpg" [src]="shirts[selected.sku].image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img width=300 height=375 src="./shirts/black.jpg" [src]="shirts[selected.sku].image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img width=400 height=500 src="./shirts/black.jpg" [src]="shirts[selected.sku].image"></amp-img>
</amp-carousel>
<p class="dots">
  <span [class]="selected.slide == 0 ? 'current' : ''" class="current"></span>
  <span [class]="selected.slide == 1 ? 'current' : ''"></span>
  <span [class]="selected.slide == 2 ? 'current' : ''"></span>
</p>
```

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/advanced-interactivity-in-amp/blob/master/static/final.html

Answer (score 0):

Navigational dots can be added by indicating  it in the CSS Custom Properties, `<style></style>`. Here's a Github sample from [Styling/Theming with AMP](https://github.com/cramforce/amphtml-fork/blob/master/spec/amp-html-components.md):

```
<head>
  <style>
    amp-carousel {
      --arrow-color: green;
      --dots: {
        opacity: 50%;
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <amp-carousel width=500 height=500>
    <div>
      <amp-img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
      </amp-img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <amp-img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
      </amp-img>
    </div>
  </amp-carousel>
</body>
```

You can also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449917/how-to-style-carousel-dots) for additonal reference.